# How to use Scrollspy & Affix in Angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I noticed that you cannot use in angular 2 components bootstrap feature like `data-spy="affix"`

Does anyone know how to use affix and scrollspy in angular 2? ([Example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy_affix&stacked=h))

Comment: use this, I'm still trying to figure out how to use affix with it though, https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-scrollspy

Comment: Have you managed to set up afix with angular2? I'm facing the same "problem".

Comment: @Ben I just created a service with a event on scroll, and a directive that sets style on the element based on some logic. I would share it but I don't have the code anymore. You could probably use this too: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll , you just need to bold your element on scroll finish, probably, i'm not sure

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) !

Comment: @SGN were you able to use scrollspy and affix in angular 2 If yes can u plz share the input

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write your small directive which would do the same thing. I'm sharing my code:

> Directive:

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[scrollPoint]'
})
export class ScrollPointDirective {
   @Input() scrollPoint: number;
   constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private renderer: Renderer,
    private el: ElementRef
 ) { }

   @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
   onWindowScroll() {
      const windowScroll = this.document.body.scrollTop;
      if (windowScroll > this.scrollPoint) {
        //add class to the native element
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'sticky-nav', true);
      } else {
        //remove class from native element
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'sticky-nav', false);
      }

   }

 }
```

The @Input scrollPoint parameter can be passed from your HTML

> HTML:

```
 <div [scrollPoint]="235">
    <ul class="nav-stacked">
       //your code
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Add CSS to the class added in the directive:

> CSS

```
.sticky-nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 90px;
  bottom: 0;
 }
```

I haven't been able to integrate affix to angular2 as well, but this did it for me.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Great explanation @AntaraDatta 

Comment: This does not make sense for sticky elements, as you're currently replacing `position: sticky` behavior with some Javascript. Either use `sticky` entirely and properly, or use `position: fixed` with some JS

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a directive to get this working (Angular 5.0).

1) Make sure bootstrap 3 is loaded

  `<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

2) Need to identify the element where the overflow scroll is visible. 

  `<aside class="affix-mc" data-spy="affix" data-target=".main-body" data-offset-top="20">`

Unless your scrollbar is originated from `window`, you need to specify the `data-target`

3) Theme your element a bit, ex. 

  `&.affix { width: 180px }`

*This approach even works for page embedded inside children of routers.*